# VAT Customer shipping goods to different country with billing address VAT magneto 2.2.3

Tags: checkout, customer-address, customer-group, customer-session, vat

Not sure how to get this working, if anyone has any idea will be appreciated for the time.

My aim is to create a module to check if the customer passing two different countries in billing and shipping.
Example: Billing address from UK with VAT number passed and customer group = zero vat customer. When I add a new shipping address in customer account section or checkout I can pass new country and address still count as a zero vat customer. Is there any way I could stop this? if there is please advice